# Access components in Joomla directly

Tags: php, html, templates, joomla, components

I have an iframe on my Joomla site which is supposed to show a component. So I would like to access a Joomla component directly without using a template. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load **joomla** content without template and modules you have to put `&tmpl=component` at the end of url.

Hope this helps

Comment: You could create a new menu item for component and put at the end of url `&tmpl=component`.